# Apache fails to start when running in FIPS mode

Tags: 20.04, apache2, encryption, openssl, ubuntu-advantage

#### Problem Description

According to the [Ubuntu FIPS 140-2 FAQ](https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-faq) document Apache2 is "known to work" when the Ubuntu Pro FIPS 140-2 modules are installed. However when I turn on the `SSLFIPS` directive for `mod_ssl` Apache fails to start with the following error:

```
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1831]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 227 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1831]: SSLFIPS invalid, rebuild httpd and openssl compiled for FIPS
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1829]: Action 'stop' failed.
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1829]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My goal is to serve a web application using Apache, with the transport protected by FIPS-validated crypto.

Relevant versions:

```
apache2 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.12
openssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.fips.16
```

---

#### Replication Steps

1. Enable `fips-updates` and reboot (I have also tried with `ua enable fips`):

```
root@apache-fips:~# ua enable fips-updates
One moment, checking your subscription first
This will install the FIPS packages including security updates.
Warning: This action can take some time and cannot be undone.
Are you sure? (y/N) y
Updating package lists
Installing FIPS Updates packages
FIPS Updates enabled
A reboot is required to complete install.
root@apache-fips:~# reboot
```

2. Verify that non-FIPS compliant algorithms fail (MD5) and that FIPS complaint algorithms succeed (SHA256):

```
root@apache-fips:~# openssl md5 /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
Error setting digest
139974463972608:error:060800C8:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for FIPS:../crypto/evp/digest.c:135:
root@apache-fips:~# openssl sha256 /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
SHA256(/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled)= 4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865
```

3. Verify that an HTTPS request succeeds:

```
root@apache-fips:~# curl -Ik https://127.0.0.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2022 19:33:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 20:11:13 GMT
ETag: "2aa6-5e84425cf6d1f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 10918
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

4. Enable `SSLFIPS` [directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslfips) to tell `mod_ssl` to use FIPS crypto:

```
root@apache-fips:~# grep SSLFIPS /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
SSLFIPS on
```

5. Restart Apache and observe the service failure:

```
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1831]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 227 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1831]: SSLFIPS invalid, rebuild httpd and openssl compiled for FIPS
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1829]: Action 'stop' failed.
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips apachectl[1829]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 10 19:36:14 apache-fips systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: As Ubuntu Pro has not been released yet it is off topic on this site.

Comment: The Ubuntu Pro rebranding is new, but the FIPS 140-2 validated Crypto modules have been available since summer 2021 under the Ubuntu Advantage banner. See [here](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3966.pdf) and [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/running-fips-140-workloads-on-ubuntu).

Even the FAQ that I linked at the beginning of my post was last updated 10 months ago.

The fact that the scheme has been renamed to Ubuntu Pro has no impact on my issue.